# create SOAP Request from WSDL by hand

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to figure out how to craft a SOAP request from just reading the WSDL.

Everything points to use a library or client, which is understandable, but I do want to know how to read a WSDL and craft a response myself if I wanted to do it in cURL or Postman. 
(I understand this is very timeconsuming to write out the XML and it's easier to use something like SoapUI, but I'd like to figure out how to build these SOAP requests generally).

I am using the NOAA as an example. http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--   **********************************************************************   

       ndfdXML.wsdl   

       John L. Schattel          MDL                4 July 2007  
       Aniesha L. Alford
       Red Hat Linux                                Apache Server  

       SOURCE CODE CONTROL INFORMATION   

       Name:  
         %PM%  
         %PID%  

       Status:  
         %PS%   

       History:  
         %PL%                                                             

       Change Document History:                                            
         %PIRC%                                                           

      *************************************************************************   -->
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
             xmlns:si="http://soapinterop.org/xsd" 
             xmlns:tns="https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl" 
             xmlns:typens="https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd" 
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
             targetNamespace="https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
            <xsd:simpleType name="sectorType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='conus'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='nhemi'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='alaska'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='guam'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='hawaii'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='puertori'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='npacocn'/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="unitType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='e'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='m'/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="formatType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='24 hourly'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='12 hourly'/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="productType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='time-series'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='glance'/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="latLonPairType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:pattern value="[\-]?\d{1,2}\.\d+,[\-]?\d{1,3}\.\d+" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="listLatLonType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:pattern value="[\-]?\d{1,2}\.\d+,[\-]?\d{1,3}\.\d+( [\-]?\d{1,2}\.\d+,[\-]?\d{1,3}\.\d+)*" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="zipCodeType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:pattern value="\d{5}(\-\d{4})?" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="zipCodeListType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:pattern value="\d{5}(\-\d{4})?( \d{5}(\-\d{4})?)*" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="featureTypeType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='Forecast_Gml2Point'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='Forecast_Gml2AllWx'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='Forecast_GmlsfPoint'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='Forecast_GmlObs'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='NdfdMultiPointCoverage'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='Ndfd_KmlPoint'/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="compTypeType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='IsEqual'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='Between'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='GreaterThan'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='GreaterThanEqualTo'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='LessThan'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='LessThanEqualTo'/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="listCityNamesType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z'\-]*( ?[a-zA-Z'\-]*)*,[A-Z][A-Z](\|[a-zA-Z'\-]*( ?[a-zA-Z'\-]*)*,[A-Z][A-Z])*" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="displayLevelType">
                <xsd:restriction base='xsd:integer'>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='1'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='2'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='3'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='4'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='12'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='34'/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value='1234'/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:complexType name="weatherParametersType">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element name="maxt"         type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element name="mint"         type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element name="temp"         type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element name="dew"          type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element name="pop12"        type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element name="qpf"      

    type="xsd:boolean"/>
.
.
.
    </definitions>
```

This was very long so I shortened it.

Primarily I want to know:

- **How to get the endpoints for each operation**
- **What do I put into the body?**
- **What are the QNames and namespace to use in the body's message?**

Every resource keeps stating to just use SoapUI or generate with a library and miss out on learning how to read the WSDL. I'm looking for the latter. Please.

Comment: I find this too complicated. It's much easier to use the new API at https://api.weather.gov/

Comment: @David uhm I'm not asking how to query the API, I'm using it as an example. I know it's complicated, that's why I'm asking for advice on how to do it.;